# linux: print last lines of a file

Tags: linux, tail

I have a JBoss that writes to a log file `console.log` line by line when it's starting.

I can follow the deploying process by `tail -F console.log`. But I want to leave it running in background and do something else.

So I use `tail -F console.log &`, it does not work because I can no longer see the information on the screen.

Is there a way that I can leave it printing in background and it shows the lines on the screen? 
It should be simple but I did not find how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: "printing in background and it shows the lines on the screen" contradictory statement, please clarify

Comment: @piyush jaiswal it runs in background but prints on the screen the last lines, what is not clear?

Comment: @piyush jaiswal for example if you do "echo 1 &" it will prints 1 on the screen while you can always get access to the terminal

Comment: Actually, a process sent to background contrinues to write to output, but this isn't convenient, because in this case output is messed up with the current active process output.